# Angularjs: UI-Grid dynamic dropdown for each row

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am using 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor' for one of my column and I want to dynamically load the drop down options which is unique for each row. I want to load the drop down options dynamically on demand via async http call.

I tried the following without success,

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
     { field: 'priority',
displayName: 'Priority',
editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
editDropdownValueLabel: 'name',
    },
]}

onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef) {
            if (colDef.field === "priority") {
                localServices.getPriorityById(rowEntity.id).then(function(data) {
                     colDef.editDropdownOptionsArray = data;
                });
            }
        });
```

Any suggestion or help to achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the usage of `editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath` instead of `editDropdownOptionsArray`

> editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath can be used as an alternative to
>   editDropdownOptionsArray when the contents of the dropdown depend on
>   the entity backing the row.

Here is a link to [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20315%20Edit%20Feature%20With%20Cascading%20Dropdowns)